# Should I use memory mapped files for my simple flow?

Tags: java, tcp, io, nio, memory-mapped-files

I am interested in implemented the following simple flow:
Client sends to a server process a simple message which the server stores. Since the message does not have any hierarchical structure IMO the best approach is to save it in a file instead of an rdb.
But I want to figure out how to optimize this since as I see it there are 2 choices:

1. Server sends a 200 OK to the client and *then* stores the message so
   the client does not notice any delay
2. Server saves the message and *then* sends the 200OK but then the
   client notices the overhead of the file I/O.

I prefer the performance of (1) but this could lead to a client thinking all went ok when actually the msg was never saved (for various error cases).
So I was thinking if I could use nio and memory mapped files.
But I was wondering is this a good candidate for using mem-mapped files?  Would using a memory mapped file guarantee that e.g. if the process crashed the msg would be saved?
In my mind the flow would be creating/opening and closing many files so is this a good candidate for memory-mapping files?

Comment: File I/O is quite quick, because data is cached in the disk cache RAM. I won't bother before measuring; and solution 1 is unsafe!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch:If I/O is so quick then why we have memory mapped option?

Comment: `mmap` can be useful for large amount of I/O -but you have to benchmark if it is useful (sometimes `mmap` might slow down). And in your case, the network might also be a bottleneck...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch:Why do I need to benchmark here?To me it seems obvious that access to HD is inherently slow.Unless we use SSD which I don't.

Comment: Because file I/O does not need to do actual disk IO if data stays in the cache. See http://linuxatemyram.com/ etc...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch:I have not tagged linux in the OP.But indeed linux is my main target

Comment: If you send 'OK' to the client before everything is OK you are basically lying to the client. The client isn't interested in getting the wrong answer more quickly.

Comment: @EJP:Yes you are right.But it seems that nio is not so faster than plain file i/o.So I am not sure what design should I prefer

Answer (score 2):

> Server saves the message and then sends the 200OK but then the client notices the overhead of the file I/O.

I suggest you test this.  I doubt a human will notice a 10 milli-second delay and I expect you should get better than this for smaller messages.

> So I was thinking if I could use nio and memory mapped files.

I use memory mapping as it can reduce the overhead per write by up to 5 micro-second.  Is this important to you?  If not, I would stick with the simplest approach.

> Would using a memory mapped file guarantee that e.g. if the process crashed the msg would be saved?

As long as the OS doesn't crash, yes.

> In my mind the flow would be creating/opening and closing many files so is this a good candidate for memory-mapping files?

Opening and closing files is likely to be fast more expensive than writing the data. (By an order of magnitude) I would suggest keeping such operations to a minimum.

You might find this library of mine interesting. https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle  It allows you to persist messages in the order of single digit micro-seconds for text and sub-micro-second for a small binary message.

Comment: I never said the client would humans.The client will be client applications

Comment: I will sure check your library. This description `persisted, messaging and event driven in memory database` seems conficting.Is it in-memory or persistant?

Comment: `I use memory mapping as it can reduce the overhead per write by up to 5 micro-second`. Is the benefit only 5ms faster or the total overhead is 5ms?

Comment: @Cratylus 5 micro-seconds is 0.005 ms. ;)  The benefit is usually much smaller.  Closer to 2 micro-seconds or 0.002 ms.

Comment: @Cratylus It is "in memory" AND "persisted", i.e. it has the performance of in memory, but is persisted by the OS as well.

Comment: @Cratylus The client applications would need to have very accurate timers, i.e. better than a milli-second to notice the difference.  This is common in high frequency trading, but in other applications is not typically important.

Comment: I don't get it.Memory mapping a file is only 5-ms faster than regular I/O?